# how to broadcast on event for a specific user?

Tags: php, laravel, events, broadcast

i am trying to build a real-time chat app with laravel and pusher. when i send a message the message is Broadcasting successfully but for all user. i want  broadcast the event for a specific user. where the logic implement and what is the logic??

Comment: Let me give you a hint to lead you in right direction. What is that one thing related to user which uniquely identifies it?

Comment: @downvoters, instead of downvoting we should fix such questions by gving them a direction :-)

Comment: for identifies a user uniquely there have user id

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PrivateChannel`. See its document here :

[Defining Broadcast Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events)

Answer (score 1):

which channel you need private or Presence Channels or public channels if you use 
you can check this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events)
then check this youtube [course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D2pnGaG6Vc&list=PLBX7qp9SQCVgozBe1qmsKFMf8TCuT3xTm) will explain all things you will practice on this topic then if you face any thing hard let me know i hope this help you ...